# C# going nuts when I declare variables with the same name as the ones in a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code (generates a quadratic function given the a, b, and c)
`Func<double, double, double, Func<double, double>> funcGenerator = (a, b, c) => f => f * f * a + b * f + c;`
Up until now, lovely.
But then, if i try to declare a variable named a, b, c or f, visual studio pops a `"A local variable named 'f' could not be declared at this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'f' which is used in a child scope."`
Basically, this fails, and I have no idea why, because a child scope doesn't even make any sense.

```
Func<double, double, double, Func<double, double>> funcGenerator =
    (a, b, c) => f => f * f * a + b * f + c;  
var f = 3; // Fails  
var d = 3; // Fine
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you're misunderstanding is that the order of declarations does not matter to the C# compiler with respect to scoping rules.

This:

```
Func<double, double, double, Func<double, double>> funcGenerator =
    (a, b, c) => f => f * f * a + b * f + c;  
var f = 3;
var d = 3;
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
var f = 3;
Func<double, double, double, Func<double, double>> funcGenerator =
    (a, b, c) => f => f * f * a + b * f + c;  
var d = 3;
```

Scopes aren't order-sensitive.  You have a local variable named `f`, and you are trying to declare another variable named `f` inside the lambda.  This is illegal according to the C# spec.

Specifically, it would conflict with the ability of lambdas to do variable capturing.  For example, this code is legal:

```
int x = 3;
Func<int> func = () => x + 1;
```

This is completely legal and executing `func()` will return `4`.  That's why you can't declare another variable `x` here inside the lambda - because the lambda actually needs to be capable of capturing the outer `x`.

Just change the name of one of the `f` variables.

Answer (score 8):

It means what it says.  You're not allowed to use the same variable name in the lambda scope and the scope containing the lambda.  The child scope is the scope of the lambda.

Comment: How does that make any sort of sense? There is no child scope. Child scope implies another set of {} in which a different variable is introduced, but that doesn't happen here. The function definition ended already.

Comment: if you introduce f in the outer scope, it is available inside the lambda, which does give a different meaning to f. In what way is this unclear?

Comment: Rubys, there *is* a child scope.  A scope does not require a `{}` in C#.  It doesn't matter that the lambda definition textually above the `var f`.

Comment: Well, the variable is declared after the lambda. I was going to say that it's the same in a for loop, but I looked into it and it seems I'm wrong. Learn something new every day, I guess. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

It can be quite tricky to work out exactly which rule of C# you've violated. As a public service I've written this handy guide that explains the differences between some of the more easily-confused scoping rules:

http://ericlippert.com/tag/simple-names/

(Start at the bottom; these are in reverse-chronological order.)

Also, you seem a bit unclear on the concept of "scope" -- which is not surprising, since in most books the word is used to mean pretty much whatever the author wants. In C# we carefully define "scope" as "the region of program text in which a particular entity may be referred to by its unqualified name". So for example, in

```
namespace A 
{
  public class B 
  {
      private int c;
      protected int d;
      public void E(int f)
      {
         int g = f;
         Func<int, int> h = i => g * i;
      }
  }
  public class K : B { }
}
```

The scope of A is everywhere. The scopes of B and K are everywhere inside a declaration of A. The scope of c is everywhere inside B. The scopes of d and E are the contents of B, K and any class derived from B or K. The scopes of f and g and h are the body of E. The scope of i is the body of the lambda.

Notice that there is a difference between scope and accessibility domain. B, K and E are *accessible* everywhere, but are only *in scope* in particular locations.

Note also that `h` is in scope *throughout* the block. It is not legal to *use* `h` before its declaration, but it is *in scope* before its declaration.

Comment: @BenVoigt: You are right, I typed that wrong. I'll fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @BenVoigt: To clarify your comment: in C#, g and h are in scope throughout the entire local declaration space which contains them. C# does not have the rule of C++ where a variable name is in scope only lexically after its declaration.  It is illegal to *use* a local before its declaration, but the local is in scope before its declaration; a subtle distinction!

Answer (score 2):

The reason the lambda's parameters and variables from the enclosing scope are in the same "namespace" (in the loose name-binding sense, not the language-feature sense) is because lambdas can close over (refer to) variables from the enclosing scope. The lambda's parameters must be distinguishable from the variables that the lambda can see:

```
int x;
Action a = () => { x = 3; };
```

That's okay, it assigns 3 to the outer `x`.

```
int x;
Action<int> a = x => { x = 3; };
```

That's no good - which `x` are we assigning 3 to?

In your example the only difference is the order of declaration. This would produce an error

```
Action a = () => { x = 3; };
int x = 2;
```

The compiler would say you can't refer to `x` before it's declared. If you then make the lambda take a parameter with the same name, we arrive at roughly your example:

```
Action<int> a = x => { x = 3; };
int x;
```

If that worked, the compiler would basically be following a rule of the form: "try the various possible interpretations of the code, and whichever one isn't erroneous, assume it's the intended meaning". C# takes a slightly safer approach, and expects you to be specific and unambiguous rather than relying on such rules to "pick a winner".

Answer (score 0):

A variable is declared inside the scope of a function. Since the lambda is compile/rewritten to some code inside that same function, it makes some kind of sense. I think the for loop where you define a variable as "first argument" of the for loop is the only exception.

Although I can imagine that it would be handy if you could reuse the variable names.

Comment: If by "handy" you mean "an endless source of hard to spot bugs", then I agree.